# grep lines matching the pattern using perl programming

Tags: perl

i want to grep pattern from a large file. But using grep it is very slow and pattern to be grep is also case insensitive. So , i read that perl is faster for file reading. Someone please tel me a way to do it in perl.

Thanks.

Comment: It might help if you could show your code.

Comment: cat File1.txt File2.txt | grep -in "exception" | grep -v "pattern"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> cat File1.txt File2.txt | grep -in "exception" | grep -v "pattern"

In perl:

```
perl -ne 'print "$.:$_" if /exception/i and !/pattern/' File1.txt File2.txt
```

or without `cat`:

```
grep -in "exception" File1.txt File2.txt | grep -v "pattern"
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep -i 'pattern' file`->`perl -lne 'print if(/pattern/i)' file`

`grep -vi 'pattern' file`->`perl -lne 'print unless(/pattern/i)' file`

If you want everything with line numebrs as well, the replace the `print`
with `print "$. $_"` in the above commands

Comment: Thanks @vijay  i think i can use this . Is  there  any option equivalent to `grep -v` means those lines which are not matching the pattern and i also want to get the line numbers .

Comment: Edited the post based on your comment

Answer (score 0):

I am doubtful that Perl would give you a performance advantage in this area. The grep utility is a pre-compiled binary written in C; Perl is an interpreted language and bears an extra performance overhead which e.g. GNU grep does not. If grep is slow the bottleneck  is most likely the file being loaded from disk into main memory. How big is the file?

FYI, grep has flags which enable case-insensitive matching and Perl-style regex syntax.

```
% grep -i 'abc' <file>    # Matches abc, ABC, aBc, etc.
% grep -i 'ab\|cd' <file> # Matches ab or cd
% grep -P 'ab|cd' <file>  # Matches ab or cd
```

An equivalent Perl program is:

```
# grep.pl
$pat = shift;
while(<>) { if(/$pat/i) { print; } }
```

which can be invoked as

```
perl grep.pl abc file1.txt file2.txt ...
```

My advice, stick with grep.

Comment: only if the problem to be solved is simple. otherwise a programming language is still indispensable